# chown -R does not set permissions of files. only directories

Tags: chown

Hello i am setting up a server nginx gives 403 Permission dinied.
I found out that somehow the command

```
chown -R root:www-data /my_directory
```

only set the permissions of directories. When i use ls -lash i get this

4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data   95 Jan 27 16:14 confirm_delete.js

any ideas how i set these permission (preferable for alldirectories at once)

Comment: What user are you running nginix as?  And does the root in your nginx.conf file match with the directory you're referencing here?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the chmod to change permissions, chown only changes owner/group on files and directories.  You'll want to use `sudo chmod -R a+rx /my_directory` to add the read and execute flags to all files and directories under /my_directory.

Comment: Hmm yes permissions changed. however nginx still does not have permissions :(